# Load consecutively numbered files in python

Tags: python, file

I have YEARS of files that follow a fairly simple naming structure and these files need to be read into a program so that their data can be dumped into a SQLite DB. The files follow the format `<YYYY>/<MM>/<D>.txt` I have some code that gets me close but it was designed to read a file that has a constant name not one that changes.

The relevant code is:

```
for root, subFolders, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, '*.txt') in files:
        with open(os.path.join(root, '<filename>'), 'r') as log:
            for lines in log:
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
import os

def list_text_files(root):
    """List all text files below a root directory."""
    for dirpath, dirname, filenames in os.walk(root):
        for filename in filenames:
            if filename.endswith('.txt'):
                yield os.path.join(dirpath, filename)

def load_file(path):
    """Load a file into the database."""
    with open(path) as fp:
        for line in fp:
            pass # code goes here

for file in list_text_files('/home/jhacker/logs'):
    load_file(file)
```

This will load *all* text files below the root.  If you want better filtering, you'll have to change it.

Comment: You can edit, for instance, by changing "if filename.endswith('.txt'):" to matching a regular expression, which allows arbitrary complexity for your matching.